# R writetable modifies numbers in dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns called Restaurant and ice.waste. I would like to save this dataframe to Excel. However in Excel the data changes. What could be the reason for this?

This is what it looks like in R:
[image]

And this is what it turns out to be in Excel:

[image]

Code I use:

```
write.table(ice.supsale,"C:/Users/../final.ice.csv",
            sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This doesn't look reproducible to me.  Are you sure your R data frame is what you posted in this question?

Comment: As A. Stam already said, this could be an issue of encoding. Can you try with `fwrite` from the `data.table` package and see if this happens there too? Or perhaps change the locale R is running on your machine. Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow Dutch person, this issue looks very familiar. It's probably because R's default write options are based on US standards (dot as decimal separator) and Excel is reading based on Dutch standards (comma as decimal separator).

I suggest using the command `write.csv2()` which uses the correct default settings for your locale.